# Vue filter Type Error and Render

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have an error in getters filters when I refresh my homepage and go to the category in the navbar I got an error Type error and render.

`TypeError: state.productsShop.filter is not a function`

`Error in render: "TypeError: state.subCategoiesShop.filter is not a function"`

`TypeError: state.subCategoiesShop.filter is not a function`

`(in promise) TypeError: state.subCategoiesShop.filter is not a function`

all this error i got from filters

**My State**

```
state: {
        filter: 'all',
        subFilter: 'all',
        products: {},
        categories: {},
        categoriesNav: {},
        products_4: {},
        productsShop: {},
        subCategoiesShop: {},
        aboutBanar: {},
    },
```

**My Getters**
here is problem my be

```
getters: {
        productsFiltered(state) {
            if (state.subFilter == 'all' && state.filter == 'all') {
                return state.productsShop
            } else {
                return state.productsShop.filter(function(product) {

                    return (state.subFilter === 'all' ? product.category_id > 0 : product.category_id === state.subFilter ) && (state.filter === 'all' ? product.subcategory_id > 0 : product.subcategory_id === state.filter )
                    // return product.category_id == state.subFilter && pr  oduct.subcategory_id == state.filter
                })
            }
            // return state.productsShop
        },
        subCategoryShopFilter(state) {
            if (state.subFilter == 'all') {
                return state.subCategoiesShop
            } else {
                return state.subCategoiesShop.filter(category => { 
                    return category.category_id === state.subFilter
                })
            }
            // return state.subCategoiesShop
        }
    },
```

**My Mutations**

```
updateCategory(state, subFilter) {
            state.subFilter = subFilter
        },
        updateSubCategory(state, filter) {
            state.filter = filter
        },
        landingFirst(state, products) {
            state.products = products
        },
        landingSecond(state, categories) {
            state.categories = categories
        },
        landingThird(state, products_4) {
            state.products_4 = products_4
        },
        categories(state, categories) {
            state.categoriesNav = categories
        },
        products(state, productsShop) {
            state.productsShop = productsShop
        },
        subcategories(state, subcategories) {
            state.subCategoiesShop = subcategories
        },
        retriveAbout(state, aboutBanar) {
            state.aboutBanar = aboutBanar
        },

    },
```

**My Actions**

Axios API from Laravel api route

```
updateCategory(context, subFilter) {
            context.commit('updateCategory', subFilter) 
        },
        updateSubCategory(context, filter) {
            context.commit('updateSubCategory', filter) 
        },
categories(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get('categories')
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('categories', response.data)
                    resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        products(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(`shop/products`)
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('products', response.data)
                    resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
        subCategories(context) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(`shop/subcategories`)
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('subcategories', response.data)
                    resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            })
        },
```

**My Shop.vue Component**

```
export default {
        props: {
            link: {
                type: String,
            },
            slug: {
                type: String,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                filter: 'all',
                categories: {},
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$store.dispatch('products')
            this.$store.dispatch('subCategories')
        },

        computed: {
            productsFilter() {
                return this.$store.getters.productsFiltered
            },
            categories1() {
                return this.categories = this.$store.state.categoriesNav
            },
            subCategoryShopFilter() {
                return this.$store.getters.subCategoryShopFilter
            },
        },
        methods: {
            changeFilter(filter) {
                this.$store.dispatch('updateSubCategory', filter)
            },  
        },
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Apparently, you're trying to apply [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on an object, instead of array. At least, you have initialized `productsShop` and `subCategoiesShop` as objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter comes from [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which can only be invoked on [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), **not on any** [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). When you initialize your state variable, you are saying `productsShop: {}` with `{}` being the shorthand initialization for an empty object, instead of `[]` which would give you an empty array.

Whether this solves your problem or not entirely depends on the rest of the code. As for the error you had initially, this is the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is only be invoked on Arrays!